# Echo an Array and make the content look pretty on the page

Tags: php

I am trying to echo out my array on each line, not bunched together.

I have tried `<br />`, this only show's on the front end, but when you look at HTML code. Its still clumped together.

```
$arrays = [];

$arrays[] = "Good";
$arrays[] = "Bad";

foreach ($arrays as $array){
    echo $array;
}
```

Result:

GoodBad

Want Result:

Good

Bad

Comment: `PHP_EOL`? https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.constants.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short of using `print_r`, to quickly get your desired result, just make this small change:

```
 echo $array."\n";
```

Make sure it's double-quotes and it will add a new line.

(That would do what `"<br />"` does on HTML)

Answer (score 0):

Try using `print_r($arrays)`. [docs](https://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php) here.

Comment: This give's me wrong resulted, its showing 
Array
(
    [a] => apple
    [b] => banana
    [c] => Array
        (
            [0] => x
            [1] => y
            [2] => z
        )
)

Answer (score 0):

Try `echo "<pre>; var_dump($arrays); echo "</pre>;`